# Linear regression: Evaluate probability of $Y>y| X=x$

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

Given a linear regression model with all the assumptions checked and validated, I would like to obtain the probability that $Y>y|X=x$. For example for the iris dataset, I would do the following to obtain the probability of $Y>5|X=1,2,3...7$:

```
plot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data=iris)
lm1<-lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data=iris)
summary(lm1)
abline(lm1)
predict(lm1, newdata=data.frame(Petal.Length=1:7))
(summary(lm1))$sigma
    pnorm(5, mean = predict(lm1, newdata=data.frame(Petal.Length=1:7)),
        sd = (summary(lm1))$sigma, lower.tail = F)
```

Is such an approach correct assuming constant variance?

Answer (score 2):

You are making various assumptions including constant variance.

Others include that a linear regression is appropriate and that the errors are normally distributed.  So you might want to look at something like the following to reassure yourself:

```
plot(lm1$residuals ~ iris$Petal.Length)
abline(h=0)

qqnorm(lm1$residuals)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am aware about the underlying assumptions. My question is, *if* the regression assumptions are valid, is this a correct methodology?

Comment: Yes: if the model is $y_i= x_i \beta+ \varepsilon_i$ with the $\varepsilon_i$ normally distributed with mean zero and a constant variance, then what you have done looks reaonable, though of course the numbers are overprecise.  `plot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data=iris); abline(h=5)` gives you a view of the information you actually have.

Comment: If X is time, would this methodology be better than a survival analysis (time to Y=y)? And how would the probability estimates (the one I used and the survival analysis) would differ?

Comment: I doubt linear regression would work then without some adjustments to justify a linear model and perhaps deal with any autocorrelation.